# How to do versioning with MongoDB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, mongodb, spring-mvc, versioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ways to implement data versioning in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185105/ways-to-implement-data-versioning-in-mongodb)

I am working with MongoDB and spring MVC and I need to know if there is any features that MongoDB provide to do some versioning for documents?

Comment: As you can see from question above, there is no such thing out of the box (like in HBase for example), but you can implement it pretty easily.

Comment: Tks for the reply, But what about the MVCC method ? does she provide the same result for versionning?

Comment: @Mirelle: Related discussion that may help: [Is it possible to implement Multi-Version Concurrency Control (MVCC) on top of MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984873/is-it-possible-to-implement-multi-version-concurrency-control-mvcc-on-top-of-m).